# Appending a dictionary to a list - I see a pointer like behavior

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I tried the following in the python interpreter:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = {1:'one'}
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[{1: 'one'}]
>>> b[1] = 'ONE'
>>> a
[{1: 'ONE'}]
```

Here, after appending the dictionary `b` to the list `a`, I'm changing the value corresponding to the key `1` in dictionary `b`. Somehow this change gets reflected in the list too. When I append a dictionary to a list, am I not just appending the value of dictionary? It looks as if I have appended a pointer to the dictionary to the list and hence the changes to the dictionary are getting reflected in the list too.

I do not want the change to get reflected in the list. How do I do it?

Comment: Chekhov You should also see this question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242933/why-in-python-list-elem-modifies-the-original-list)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [List changes unexpectedly after assignment](/q/2612802/4518341) except that the object is a dict and the reference is an element of a list, not a name.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You are correct in that your list contains a *reference* to the original dictionary.

`a.append(b.copy())` should do the trick.

Bear in mind that this makes a shallow copy. An alternative is to use [`copy.deepcopy(b)`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html), which makes a deep copy.

Answer (score 40):

Also with **dict**

```
a = []
b = {1:'one'}

a.append(dict(b))
print a
b[1]='iuqsdgf'
print a
```

result

```
[{1: 'one'}]
[{1: 'one'}]
```

Comment: Not sure if it's fast enough as copy(), but seems to be faster than deepcopy(). Maybe with complicated dictionary schema it'll be close to deepcopy() because dict() creates a new dictionary.

Comment: @selotec To be clear, this is a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Answer (score 3):

use copy and deep copy

> http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html