# Issue with pop() and append()

Tags: python, list, append

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

```
res = []
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
s.pop() 
res.append(s)
print res
s.pop()                                                                                  
res.append(s)
print res
```

The above python code gives the following result

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I don't understand why pop on s will affect res. I mean the print result should be

```
[[1,2,3,4,5]]
[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Comment: You are working with the *same list*. You've added `s` to `res` *twice*, but it's still **the same list**

Comment: Before adding s to res, I pop the last item in s. So the two items in res should be different, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is OK - because res will hold the same reference as s(to the same object- in this case the array).

To solve this problem use this:

```
res = []
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
s.pop()
res.append(list(s))
print res
s.pop()
res.append(list(s))
print res
```

also take a look at :

[How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

[python: Appending a dictionary to a list - I see a pointer like behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244810/python-appending-a-dictionary-to-a-list-i-see-a-pointer-like-behavior)

Comment: thanks for the reference links.@Dozon Higgs

Answer (score 0):

> Every value in Python is a reference (pointer) to an object.
>   Assignment always copies the value (which is a pointer); two such
>   pointers can thus point to the same object.

To get the needed result you need to copy the initial list:

```
res = []
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
s.pop()
res.append(s[:])
print(res)
s.pop()
res.append(s[:])
print(res)
```

The same can be done using `list.copy()` function:

```
...
res.append(s.copy())
...
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @RomanPerekhrest. Now I understand.