# Mapping values from for-loop lines to a list of tuples?

Tags: python, mapping

For the following code, I'm trying to print out the values within a list of tuples that are mapped from the line to it based on column headers. However, the mapping seems to go awry and do not give me the values I want.

```
import itertools as it

def buc(column_headers, tuples):
    row_dict = {}   
    attribs = [1,2]
    measure = 10

    # generate binary table based on number of columns
    binaries = [i for i in it.product(range(2), repeat=(len(attribs)))]

    for line in binaries:
        line = list(line)

        # replace binary of 1 with 'ALL' or 0 with value from input attribs
        for index, item in enumerate(line):
            if (item == 1):
                line[index] = 'ALL'
            elif (item == 0):
                line[index] = attribs[index]

        line.append(measure)
        print(line)

        # map column values to column heading by index and store in row_dict (e.g. {'A': 1, 'B': 'ALL', 'M': 100} )
        for i in range(len(line)):
            row_dict[column_headers[i]] = line[i]
        tuples.append(row_dict)

    print(tuples)
```

The following is the current output I get:

```
>>> buc(['A', 'B', 'M'], [])
[1, 2, 10]
[1, 'ALL', 10]
['ALL', 2, 10]
['ALL', 'ALL', 10]
[{'A': 'ALL', 'B': 'ALL', 'M': 10}, {'A': 'ALL', 'B': 'ALL', 'M': 10}, {'A': 'ALL', 'B': 'ALL', 'M': 10}, {'A': 'ALL', 'B': 'ALL', 'M': 10}]
```

The correct output I want should be the following, where the lines is mapped to the tuples correctly, based on index of the column headings:

```
>>> buc(['A', 'B', 'M'], [])
[1, 2, 10]
[1, 'ALL', 10]
['ALL', 2, 10]
['ALL', 'ALL', 10]
[{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'M': 10}, {'A': '1', 'B': 'ALL', 'M': 10}, {'A': 'ALL', 'B': '2', 'M': 10}, {'A': 'ALL', 'B': 'ALL', 'M': 10}]
```

Where have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your list `tuples` only contains a reference to the original dictionary. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244810/python-appending-a-dictionary-to-a-list-i-see-a-pointer-like-behavior). You can fix this by [copying](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) the dictionary.

Replace

```
tuples.append(row_dict)
```

with

```
tuples.append(row_dict.copy())
```