# Why clearing a list of a list clears all lists

Tags: python

In this code I'm adding zeros to an empty list, then when it contains 9 zeros that list is added to another list which is called board, then I clear the row of 9 zeros and repeat the process 9 times again:

```
    row = []
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            row.append('0')
        self.board.append(row)
        row.clear()
    print(board)
```

After some prints I've understand that before the outer loop ends the board contains all 9 rows of 9 zeros but when `row.clear()` is executed for the last time it clears all the rows of zeros giving me a result of a list that contains 9 empty lists, which of course is not what I want, I know how to solve it but I don't understand why when the loop reaches the end all internal lists of zeros are clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a single `row` list instance that exists 9 times in `self.board`. Clearing one has the effect of clearing them all, since they're all the same list.

At the simplest, you'll need to (shallow-)copy the list, so there are 9 separate lists:

```
self.board.append(row[:])
# or
self.board.append(list(row))
# or
self.board.append(row.copy())
```

(Shallow-copying here is fine, since the value within is a string, and strings are immutable.)

You could also use [a list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the fact you can multiply a list to repeat it to populate your board in one swoop:

```
self.board = [['0'] * 9 for x in range(9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895430/python-append-an-original-object-vs-append-a-copy-of-object)

If the objects are mutable, append will only add the pointer to that board object (not the value)

you can use .copy() to copy the value

> self.board.append(row.copy())

if you dont want to update it