# Python, Deep learning, gradient descent method example

Tags: python, gradient

I am studying `gradient descent` method with **Deep learning from scratch**. In the book example, there are some code that is hard to understand. this is the code.

```
def gradient_descent(f, init_x, lr = 0.01, step_num = 100):
    x = init_x
    x_hist = []
    for i in range(step_num):
        x_hist.append(x) # plot with x_hist
        grad = numerical_gradient(f, x)
        x -= lr * grad
    return x, x_hist

def function_2(x):
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2

init_x = np.array([-3.0, 4.0])
x, x_hist = gradient_descent(function_2, init_x, lr = 0.1, step_num = 100)
```

I'm try to plot `x_hist` to see the decrease of 'x'. But when I print `x_hist`, it comes like this.

```
x_hist
[array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10]),
array([-6.11110793e-10,  8.14814391e-10])]
```

I can fix this problem if i change `x_hist.append(x)` to `x_hist.append(x.copy())`.
Unfortunately, I don't know why this is different. Can anyone tell me the different between those?(Sorry for the English)

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244810/python-appending-a-dictionary-to-a-list-i-see-a-pointer-like-behavior

Answer (score 1):

Your list x_hist contains a reference to x, not the value. So correcting it by x_hist.append(x.copy()) is a good way.