# How to import entire sheet to list via openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a problem with importing data from the spreadsheet. 
I'm trying create list containing all data. But only last row is added to list.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "excel.xlsx"
l_data = load_workbook(path)
sheet = l_data.active
c_row = sheet.max_row
c_column = sheet.max_column
out_data=[]
dict={}
for a in range(1, c_row + 1):
    for b in range(1, c_column + 1):
        ob = sheet.cell(row=a, column=b)
        dict[b] = ob.value
    out_data.append(dict)
```

I need such output data:
[ {1:"row1_call1",2:"row1_call2"},{1:"row2_call1",2:"row2_call2"} ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that one:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "excel.xlsx"
l_data = load_workbook(path)
sheet = l_data.active
c_row = sheet.max_row
c_column = sheet.max_column
out_data=[]
dict={}
for a in range(1, c_row + 1):
    for b in range(1, c_column + 1):
        ob = sheet.cell(row=a, column=b)
        dict[b] = ob.value

    out_data.append(str(dict))

print(out_data)
```

It changes type of dict values. So only this line changes from:

```
out_data.append(dict)
```

to:

```
out_data.append(str(dict))
```

Check that site if you want know more appending dict to list:
[python: Appending a dictionary to a list - I see a pointer like behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244810/python-appending-a-dictionary-to-a-list-i-see-a-pointer-like-behavior)

So this is also working:

```
out_data.append(dict.copy())
```

Comment: In that case, i will receive [ 'row1_call1','row2_call1']. And i need it [{1: 'row1_call1'},{1: 'row2_call1'}]

Comment: Edited that. check that one.

Comment: Yes, that's it :)  Tnx4help

Comment: `dict` is a keyword so it's not a good idea to use it as a variable name