# Later lines of code seemingly affecting how earlier lines are executed. What's going on?

Tags: python

The below block of code works as intended

```
patient = Patient()
patient.log = []
patient.id = "xyz"
patient.example_attribute = []
ALL_PATIENT_LOG = []

def update(patient, attribute, argument, replace = False):
    now = datetime.now()
    entry = {"argument": argument, "attribute": attribute, "time": now.strftime("%H:%M on %d/%m/%y")}
    patient.log.append(entry)
```

But when I add the following to the end of update

```
    entry["patient_id"] = patient.id #  we also need to include the patient's ID for the global log
    ALL_PATIENT_LOG.append(entry)
    if replace:
        patient.__dict__[attribute] = [argument]
    else:    
        patient.__dict__[attribute].append(argument)
```

the patient.log entry is changed such that it also contains the patient id

This violates my understanding of how python works, as I thought that later lines cannot affect how earlier lines are executed. What have I misunderstood which prevents me from understanding why this executes the way it does? How could I change this code to get the desired behaviour? (two different log entries depending on whether its being appended to the patient log or the ALL_PATIENT_LOG)

Comment: lists don't contain copies of objects, but references to them

Comment: Note that you are asking two questions here. Both "what is wrong", and "how do I change this to get what I intended". The first is easy to answer, the second can have multiple answers, and depends based on prefferences and application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```py
patient.log.append(entry)
```

Appends the `entry` dictionary to the `patient.log`, it does not "add" the elements of the `entry` dictionary to the list. So when you in the next line call

```py
entry["patient_id"] = patient.id
```

You are changing the `entry` dictionary, and since the `patient.log` is referencing to that dictionary, it will have the updated information when you look up that list.

A way to solve this, is to create a `copy` of the dictionary, instead of a reference, also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244810/python-appending-a-dictionary-to-a-list-i-see-a-pointer-like-behavior) :

```py
patient.log.append(entry.copy())
```

As that post also mentions, make sure you understand how `copy` works, as it might not always work as intended. Especially if there are references within the object you copy.